# Is it possible to use pander tables in jekyll page with kramdown

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, pander

I tried to use [pander](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pander/index.html) tables in a markdown page that is generated from R-markdown files like Yihui describes in an [example page](http://yihui.name/knitr-jekyll/2014/09/jekyll-with-knitr.html).

In my `_config.yml` I have the markdown type set to `markdown: kramdown`. I know that some things are different in this markdown type compared to the markdown [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) uses per default. So if I compile my page in RStudio with knitr the table looks alright. If I compile the page with jekyll the table looks not formatted right.

````
```{r key}
library(pander)
LETTERSplus <- c(LETTERS, "_", ".", ",", "-")
key <- sample(LETTERSplus)
names(key) <- LETTERSplus
pander(key)
```
````

Compiled with knitr inside RStudio it looks alright:

[image]

Compiled with Jekyll it looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to use `kable` since it formats the table differently and there is now column wrap if the table is too long.

Do I have to set some special pandoc options to make this work? Options to define the markup type pandoc has to output? I don't see any other options inside the `pander()` function.

Comment: I suspect `kramdown` uses the PHP Markdown Extra syntax, so the default `multiline` table format might not work, but you have to use the `rmarkdown` format. To do so, pass the `style = 'rmarkdown` argument to `pander` or enable this globally by `panderOptions('table.style', 'rmarkdown')`. Let me know if this resolves the problem.

Comment: This worked! But only if I set it globally. I could not work out how to pass things directly in the `pander()` call, even though some of the examples in the help system suggested this should work. It worked only if I used `pandoc.table()`. `pandoc.table(text_freq, split.tables=90, justify="right")
` worked, `pander(text_freq, split.tables=90, justify="right")
` did not. I had to set the chunk to `'asis'` output for this.

Comment: That's very strange and unexpected. Can you please submit a bug report on [GH](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander) including the output of `devtools::session_info()`?